# Spring Data Mongo Cosmos DB Invalid Character

Tags: spring, azure-cosmosdb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use Cosmos DB Mongo API with Spring Data Mongo but I can't seem to get it working from some reason. I took the Spring Boot Data Mongo example project and just swapped it to point to my Cosmos DB Mongo API instance and I continuously get

```
"Errors":["The input name presented contains invalid character '='."]
```

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

--

```
public class Customer {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

--

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

This is the full stack trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 2: 'Message: {"Errors":["The input name presented contains invalid character '='."]}
ActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0' on server bl4prdddc02-docdb-1.documents.azure.com:10255. The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 2, "errmsg" : "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input name presented contains invalid character '='.\"]}\r\nActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0", "$err" : "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input name presented contains invalid character '='.\"]}\r\nActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: 'Message: {"Errors":["The input name presented contains invalid character '='."]}
ActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0' on server bl4prdddc02-docdb-1.documents.azure.com:10255. The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 2, "errmsg" : "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input name presented contains invalid character '='.\"]}\r\nActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0", "$err" : "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input name presented contains invalid character '='.\"]}\r\nActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0" }
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2139) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:484) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:1049) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:858) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:799) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:80) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at hello.Application.run(Application.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: 'Message: {"Errors":["The input name presented contains invalid character '='."]}
ActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0' on server bl4prdddc02-docdb-1.documents.azure.com:10255. The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 2, "errmsg" : "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input name presented contains invalid character '='.\"]}\r\nActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0", "$err" : "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The input name presented contains invalid character '='.\"]}\r\nActivityId: bbd7a66e-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/514defcb-ac21-44e6-a8e0-c7b785523c6c/services/f173b6ae-dc85-49b6-aa62-47cd6a2e7502/partitions/77795815-5c06-4ded-a979-25c46b054119/replicas/131632137400221103p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.receiveMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:268) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:37) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.insertCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:118) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.InsertOperation.executeCommandProtocol(InsertOperation.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:139) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:426) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:417) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:845) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:828) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:337) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:298) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:264) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:201) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$9.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1054) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:482) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: could you please send a sample document and the entire source code that reproduces the problem (this one is missing quite few things) to askcosmosmongoapi@microsoft.com?

Comment: @alekseys - if the question is to be asked and answered here, then any additional information needs to be included within the question here, and not sent externally outside of StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon the problem can only be reproduced with original source code and if the OP didn't post it, it is likely sensitive and the best way to to get it is out of band. The answer can still be posted back to the thread.